# Disable webservice after application has started

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

In short, I have a web service that I want to completely disable after the user has clicked certain choices in the application. I want the equivalent of never having added the service at all so that if you try to send a request to the endpoint no definition should be returned and no web service method shall work anymore.

I want to do this without recycling the application pool. I have tried to just use RouteTable.Routes.Remove() but that did not work.

The code used to add the service:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.Add( new ServiceRoute("my url here"), new ServiceHost(), typeof( MyService) ) );
```